# Vue router is not working on the build version

Tags: vue.js, build, vue-router

I have developed a Vue3 app with only one route. It is working fine on the development version but after "npm run build" the route is not working on the build version.

Here is the **vite.config.js** file

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the **router/index.js** file

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/:shop_id",
            name: "home",
            component: HomeView,
        },
    ],
});

export default router;
```